# Type wrapping of non-atomic types in golang

Tags: github, go, time

I'm new to golang and am trying to understand a code example of type wrapping for the "non-atomic" type time.Time.

The type extension in question is from the Go client for GDAX on github, [go-coinbase-exchange project](https://github.com/preichenberger/go-coinbase-exchange).

The expected behavior would be for Time variables from the project (coinbase.Time), which are of `type Time time.Time` (as defined in the project's [time.go](https://github.com/preichenberger/go-coinbase-exchange/blob/master/time.go) file) to behave something like the following example for extending the "atomic" type `int` (from [blog.riff.org](http://blog.riff.org/2014_07_19_golang_fun_adding_methods_to_primitive_types) in that they might follow a kind of "inheritance" from the base type for functions like Time.format (from [golang's standard implementation of time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format):

```
package main
import "fmt"
type Int int

func (i Int) Add(j Int) Int {
  return i + j
}

func main() {
  i := Int(5)
  j := Int(6)
  fmt.Println(i.Add(j))
  fmt.Println(i.Add(j) + 12)
}
```

But if I modify the code example from the project's `List Account Ledger` example found in [Readme.md](https://github.com/preichenberger/go-coinbase-exchange/blob/master/README.md) to include a print function which might otherwise give me a human-readable view of the CreatedAt struct variables (as follows), I get a compiler error saying that "type `coinbase.Time` has no field or method `Format`":

```
for _, e := range ledger {
    print("Entry Creation: ")
    fmt.Printf(e.CreatedAt.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999+00"))
}
```

The expected behavior inside the `for` loop would be for it to print the ledger entries in a human-readable format. I can get the contents of the structs, but I'm not really sure how to then use the resulting `wall`, `ext` and `loc` members.

For example, inserting `fmt.Printf("%#v", e.CreatedAt)` into the `for` loop gives me a representation of the time that looks something like this:

`coinbase.Time{wall:0x3015a123, ext:63612345678, loc:(*time.Location)(nil)}
{806986000 63638738354 <nil>}`

I can also see that `wall` is of type `uint64`, that `ext` is of type `int64` and that `loc` is just GMT/UTC=0 by formatting the variable as a string because `fmt.Printf("%s", e.CreatedAt)` gives me output which is similar to the following:

`{%!s(uint64=712345678) %!s(int64=63612345678) %!s(*time.Location=<nil>)}`

It seems like I'm missing something. I've requested further information through [issues tab on github](https://github.com/preichenberger/go-coinbase-exchange/issues/24), but maybe this is a nube question. So I'm not sure how quick the response time would be, and I'm interested in the more general case for extending non-atomic types in go.

Comment: The question is a little confusing - `int` is not atomic, hence the need for [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/).

Comment: Not only is `int` not atomic, there are no "atomic" types in Go. The only atomic operators are in `sync/atomic`.

Comment: Channels are the only atomic base type in Go.

Comment: @Adrian: `sending` and `receiving` are "atomic" operations, but reading and writing channel values are not. That often triggers race conditions when users try to replace channel values concurrently to alter the cases in select blocks.

Comment: Fair point, only channel ops are atomic, not the values themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Named types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) do not inherit any methods from the underlying type (indeed there is no inheritance at all in Go); you must cast to the underlying type to call any methods from that type:

```
(time.Time(e.CreatedAt)).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999+00")
```

Comment: This is call a "type conversion". There are no casts in Go.

Comment: Yes, it's called type conversion in the spec, but type conversion to an underlying type has no practical difference from what is called type casting in every other language on Earth.

Comment: @Adrian That's the ticket. Thanks.